# Subclassing SKLabelNode error with Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have the following class that is a subclass of SKLabelNode. This class will not work without the

```
override init(){
        super.init()
    }
```

call. It seems that SKLabelNode is trying to call an init() method with no parameters, or something else is going on somewhere that is causing this issue.

Here is the simplified class.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class PulsatingText: SKLabelNode {

    override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    init (fontNamed:String!, theText: String!, theFontSize: CGFloat!){
        super.init(fontNamed: fontNamed)
        self.text = theText
        self.fontSize = theFontSize
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

If i remove the

```
override init(){
            super.init()
        }
```

I get a runtime crash with the following error logged to the console.

**fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'MobileTutsInvaderz.PulsatingText'**

Here is how I am calling the method.

let invaderText = PulsatingText(fontNamed: "ChalkDuster", theText: "INVADERZ", theFontSize:50)

I am also including a image of the stack trace below.

[image: ,]

Comment: Default initializer for `SKLabelNode` is `init(fontNamed fontName: String!)`, did you try to override it?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls this class?

Comment: @AndyHeard I udated the post to show I am calling the class.

Comment: @NikitaIvaniushchenko I did not try to override it either No, what you see in this class is it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the `init()` method. Because the default `init()` method gets called everytime you initialize a `SKLabelNode`. You can test it by implementing the `override init()` and add an `println` statement like that:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    println("test")
}
```

If you now init a labelnode like that:

```
var label:PulsatingText = PulsatingText(fontNamed: "Arial", theText: "hey", theFontSize: 12)
```

The `println("test")` will get called.

Comment: It makes sense that the init would be called eventually, but it is strange that it calls the init() method of the subclass.

Comment: Can you explain more why it would be calling the subclasses init() method.? I am trying to understand why it is working this way. Thanks

Comment: I agree it seems odd. Sometimes Swift does not obey common sense.

Answer (score -1):

Since you only want to add `convenience` initializer and leave the rest as is, you don't need to override designated initializers. So just change your code like this:

```
class PulsatingText: SKLabelNode {

    convenience init (fontNamed:String!, theText: String!, theFontSize: CGFloat!){
        self.init(fontNamed: fontNamed)
        self.text = theText
        self.fontSize = theFontSize
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives an error, and I am actually doing a little more than this. I simplified my init method. To get the point across as to why super.init() was being called.

Comment: What is XCode version you use? I use 6.2. Can you add your error?

Comment: Xcode 12.2 gives this error: `Convenience initializer for 'PulsatingText' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than chaining to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init')`